# Trouble when passing a php variable as an argument in mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to use a php variable as a search term when querying a mysql database, first I get the variables from the HTML form:

```
<?php
//Create variables
$vals = array($_POST["id_number"], $_POST["id_name"], $_POST["id_submitname"]);
$keys = array('idno_1', 'name_2', 'subname_3');
//combine keys to arrays
$var = array_combine($keys, $vals);
//santise variables
$variables = filter_var_array($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$idno = $variables['idno_1'];
$name = $variables['name_2'];
$subname = $variables['subname_3'];
```

After connecting to the database I run the query:

```
  //Select entry from table and display
if (!$idno == '')
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `healthsafety` WHERE ID = '$idno'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    }
elseif (!$name == '')
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `healthsafety` WHERE LOWER (nameinvolved) = LOWER ('$name')");
    }
else
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `healthsafety` WHERE LOWER (submitbyname) = LOWER ('$subname')");
    }

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

It is not returning anything from the db, when I select * FROM without trying to use the variable as a search it displays all entries ok, am I making an error when passing the variable to the query? I've tried different combinations of quotes, back ticks and using other variables for the query. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have to be use lower like this:  LOWER('$name')

Comment: What do you get when you print the query? `echo $sql`, `echo $result`

Comment: `LOWER` is a MySQL `function`, and like in PHP, you pass the function arguments in brackets `()`

Comment: It's never a good idea to send direct user input to database without escaping it. use mysqli_real_escape_string($name) in the code.

Comment: Hi All, I know about the parentheses on the LOWER function, I have corrected it. Does FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING not escape and check user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`LOWER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) is a function and the arguments needs to be wrapped in parentheses.

Your query should look like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `healthsafety` 
WHERE LOWER(nameinvolved) = LOWER('$name')");
```

For easier debugging, I'd first print out the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `healthsafety` 
WHERE LOWER(nameinvolved) = LOWER('$name')";
echo $result;
```

... and then run it manually using the MySQL Interactive shell or using web interfaces like phpMyAdmin. That could help you isolate the issue further and then figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks for the response, I've added the parentheses in ( I had them in originally I had just taken them out to check if they were causing a problem). I have run the query through the web interface but obviously I can't pass variables, thats why I'm thinking I have a problem with the variable being passed to the query. If i just use a string in the query it runs fine.

Comment: @user3112067: No, run the PHP script, and **echo** the query. Execute the script, copy the output, run that manually using web interface. Now does that work?

Comment: thanks again: I've echo'ed the variable and it returns 1039 which was the string passed from the html form, then I pass the query to mysql and print_r the $result array, it returns: **mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 58 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )**, any ideas?

Comment: hey yes that worked, I went through my code and noticed I had a semi colon at the end of a while loop condition that was preventing the results being echo'ed to the HTML page. Many thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

First you needed to be sure that all data are correct. then Try this:

```
if (isset($idno) &&  !$idno == '')
        {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `healthsafety` WHERE ID = $idno";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        }
    else if (isset($name) && !$name == '')
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `healthsafety` WHERE LOWER (nameinvolved) = LOWER ('$name')");
        }
    else
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `healthsafety` WHERE LOWER (submitbyname) = LOWER ('$subname')");
        }

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Hi Awlad, that didn't work. I think the problem is with passing the variable not actually the if else statement.

Comment: just print all variables before database query execution